# namedtuple in Python 2.5

Tags: python, python-2.5

I am aware that the `namedtuple` class exists from 2.6 onwards.
Is there a way of implementing similar functionality in Python 2.5 so normal tuples can be made to achieve this?

```
Student = namedtuple('Student', 'name serial')
```

Comment: If you don't need exactly the functionality of a named tuple, you can also use [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308) class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a recipe to [implement named tuples in Python 2.4](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261-named-tuples/) and later. You can compare this to the actual implementation of named tuples in, say, Python 2.7 [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l287).

Answer (score 3):

The actual source of the `namedtuple` in Python is this recipe here: [Named Tuples](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261-named-tuples/).

> The resulting recipe has been well received, so it was proposed and accepted for inclusion in the collections module for Py2.6.